# SetContentView cannot find resource

Tags: android

I am new to Android environment. For some reason, I am getting errors when trying to build. Specifically, these types where by the `activity_main.xml` layout file is being reported as not being found. However, I do see it there. There seems like there might be something messed up in my environment but I don't know what? I consistently get these types of error whether the resource exists or not.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "I do see it there" there being where ?

Comment: once try checking whether the R.java file is created or not. If its not check if there is any error in the xml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these.........

**-** 1st when you create a `,XML` file like **main.xml** file, you will need a `Class` that **extends** `Activity` and that **must be mentioned** in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**- Clean** the Project.

**- Close** Eclipse, and start it again. **Don't Restart but Close it**. Eclipse does behave weirdly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are importing the wrong "R" file..

Check your imports in your activity.. see if you have import android.R;

If so, delete it.. and make sure you import the proper R file for your own project

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error in one of your XML files, the resource compiler may not have generated an R.java file. This would then cause errors when you reference any resource ID in code.

Always fix any problems in the XML files before worrying about resource IDs not being found in code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if activity_main.xml exists in the res/layout folder (make sure it's not inside res/xml instead). If it exists in the correcti directory, try opening it and check if there are any errors.

Also, rebuild your project by running *Project -> Clean* to make sure all resources are reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check for typos in your package names. If you have renamed any of your package folders, 90% of the time this error is caused by typos in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Check if your  matches your package names on app/java/com/packagename/yourappname